# SQL Server - executing direct query vs. executing with sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm checking the behavior of some ORMs and Micro-ORM and checking how they generate queries sent to the database (SQL Server).

What I notice is 2 main methods of execution:

Direct execution of query:

```
select * from mytable
insert into mytable(val1, val2) values (@val1, @val2)
```

or something that users sp_executesql like this:

```
  exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO mytable(val1, val2) VALUES (@p0, @p1)',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p0=1,@p1=NULL
```

what is the difference between the 2 methods? which one is faster? and does it influence the execution plan?

Comment: "which one is faster" - do you honestly think that if there was a measurable difference between the two, such that there was always a faster one versus a slower one, we wouldn't have just all switched to using the faster one?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so why use one over the other? there might be an impact on the execution plan.

Comment: Guess: ORM written before SQL Server 2005 became popular have used sp_executesql to reuse query plan (prior to SQL Server 2005 "raw" queries couldn't reuse execution plan).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parameters for sp_executesql (as in your example above) and the text of the statement doesn't change between executions then the execution plan generated for the first execution will probably be used for subsequent executions. So it is likely to be as performant as multiple executions of the standard statement (as in your first code sample).

However the contents of the sp_executesql statement are compiled and executed as an execution plan separate from the execution plan of the batch that called sp_executesql, so in this way it does have an influence on the execution plan.

The primary difference between the sp_executesql stored procedure and a standard direct statement is that the former can be used for executing dynamically created statements.